# We need more close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closing

Now that we're trying to course correct the site to Q&A, we need to close many subjective and offtopic questions, which makes the 12 close votes not enough.

Could we have more until we have moderators at least?

It can be done for > 1K rep users only, and I'd be ok for it to be temporary (again, until we have moderators to help)

Comment: Don't reopen this.  It was an issue once, it was bumped up to 20 and later reset to 12.  There is no reason to keep this open, it should remain only for historical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has now been implemented, announced earlier today in chat. Those with the ability to close can now cast 20 votes per day.

edit: due to request, this has been reverted to 12.

Comment: Oh did we close too much?

Comment: no, we now have diamonds.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely, we really need moderators with solo-votes, but until then we need to be able to close these questions. We only have a couple of people with close privileges, after all.

Comment: Not a couple, 25 at the time of writing this. Moderators could be useful, though.